# ShopBot router software crashes after machine moves past limit switch

Tags: software, cnc

We just bought a [ShopBot](https://www.shopbottools.com/) for our Workshop and set it up ourselves. The ShopBot Software crashed every time we manually moved the gantry past its magnetic limit switches. Sometimes the software also crashed during a standard X-Y-Zeroing procedure. The machine has both limit switches and hard-stops installed that prevent the gantry from rolling off the rails after passing the limit switch.

Have any of you experienced a similar problem? How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a ShopBot at our Maker Space and have had a similar issue. In short, adjust the distance between your limit-switch trigger screws and your hard-stop. If your hard-stop is too far away from your limit-switch trigger screw and allows the magnetic limit-switch to disengage i.e. turn off after passing the limit switch the software encounters an unexpected state that is currently not properly handled. There should never be a scenario where your shop bot is outside of its limits and the limit-switch is not triggered.

You can simply check if this is the problem by manually moving the gantry to its extremes and check if the red light on the limit switch turns off when hitting the switch and if your distance is too large on again after passing the switch before hitting the hard-stop.